# How to clean up unused meta mask event listeners

Tags: metamask

If I register a meta mask event listener using:

```js
provider.on('accountsChanged', accounts => {
  console.log('accounts:', accounts)
})
```

Is there a way to clean this listener? I'm use Vue.js which means if the listener is registered upon loading of the component it's gonna register a new listener every time the component is loaded. I could use a custom workaround, checking if the listener has already been registered but maybe there's a proper way to do this that I haven't found in the metamask documentation yet. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Struggled a bit with this myself since it is not very well documented. This is what worked for me in the end:

```js
provider.on("accountsChanged", handleAccountsChanged)

function handleAccountsChanged() {
  // do something
}

// When leaving the page (Vue 3 - Composition API)
onUnmounted(() => {
  if (provider.removeListener) {
    provider.removeListener("accountsChanged", handleAccountsChanged)
  }
})
```

Hope that helps anyone.